# How can I change the data-icon value using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, divi

I have an ajax "load more/show less" button on my blog. The default button text is "More Posts" with a down arrow icon.

[More Posts button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wNwK.png)

When the button is clicked, the text changes to "Less Posts", but I can't figure out how to change the icon to an up icon.

[Less Posts button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJWWB.png)

In the code below, I need to change the value of **data-icon="7"** to **data-icon="6"**.

```
<a class="et_pb_button et_pb_custom_button_icon el-pagination-button el-button el-show-less" href="https://wbj1.flywheelsites.com/blog/?el_dbe_page" data-icon="7">Less Posts</a>
```

I tried this jQuery snippet without any luck, but I'm not very skilled in javascript or jQuery so it could be wrong:

```
document.getElementByClassName("el-show-less").setAttribute("data-icon"), "6");
```

Comment: [What do querySelectorAll and getElementsBy* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the value of `data-icon` using pure Javascript you can handle that like this

```
let element = document.querySelector('.el-show-less');
element.dataset.icon = 7;
```

Using jQuery you can perform that like this

```
let element = $('.el-show-less');
element.data('icon', 4);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both solutions, and it didn't work. Could this be because the class '.el-show-less' isn't applied to the button until it's clicked?

Comment: If that's the case you have to applied that change when the button is clicked and the `.el-show-less` class is applied to the Button